# How to list a series of classes that contain the same attributes and assign a different z-index for each

Tags: css, class, z-index

How can I list a series of classes that contain the same attributes and assign a different z-index for each. For example

```
.class1 .class2 .class3 .class4 {
background color:red;
height:70px;
width:40px;
z-index: 1,2,3,4
}
```

where .class1 would have the z-index 1, .class2 would have the z-index 2 and so forth

Comment: use SASS/LESS ... no way with CSS unless you write it for each one manually

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in Javascript/jQuery? I'm not familiar with SASS/LESS :/

Comment: yes it can be done with JS/jQuery

Comment: The only good reason to introduce JavaScript/jQuery here would be if you need to change your `z-index` values based on user behavior (e.g. after a click on something). Remember: HTML for content and structure; CSS for style; JavaScript for behavior.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do for what you're describing. Unless you want to use a preprocessor. You can't do them all with a single declaration in plain CSS. But this is pretty much what a preprocessor would compile to anyway.

```
.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4 {
    background color: red;
    height: 70px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.class2 {
    z-index: 2;
}

.class3 {
    z-index: 3;
}

.class4 {
    z-index: 4;
}
```